# HostGator and 123reg

Tags: domains, web-hosting, domain-registration, hostgator

I am trying to set up my website to work with Hostgator, and 123reg.

I have mapped my IP address that HostGator gave me, to my 123reg domain name I just bought.

What I did was the following:

1. Mapped the IP address to my domain name using 123reg (control    panel).
2. I also changed the Nameservers values (in 123reg) to what    HostGator gave me.
3. I have setup a Joomla Service using the    HostGator Control Panel. everything seemed to be working fine. Joomla    gave me credentials, an admin URL and everything.

Now the problem that has been bothering me is, that WHATEVER I type it redirects me to the 123reg default site as if my changes had not taken any place.

For example:

```
www.mydomain.com -> 123reg default page
www.mydomain.com/home -> 123reg default page
www.mydomain.com/admin -> 123reg default page
www.mydomain.com/whatever -> 123reg default page
```

Can somebody please help me through?

Comment: Minor point, but if you change the NAMESERVERS at 123reg then you don't need to "map the IP address to your domain at 123reg" as well. Changing the NAMESERVERS will use HostGator's DNS, so any DNS changes at 123reg will be ignored. But, as stated in the answers below, changing the NAMESERVERS will take some time to propagate around the internet. To limit this delay you should ideally reduce the [TTL (Time To Live) in the DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records) before changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How long ago did you do this? While registrars will tell you it takes 24-48 hours for your DNS set up to propagate around the world, in reality, you could notice changes in less than an hour. So you need to wait a while for things to happen.

Answer (score 1):

In your cmd prompt, do a `nslookup mydomain.com` and make sure the correct nameservers display for HostGator. Also to be sure your ISP DNS is cleared, do a `ipconfig /flushdns`.